# Vue Render Images inside V-for

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js

I am trying to render an image inside v-for, but I can only catch it as a string.

```
  <tr
      class="bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200"
      v-for="currentView in getDashboard()"
      :key="currentView.id"
    >
      <td class="px-4 py-3">
        <img :src=" {{currentView["avatarUrl"]}}" width="40px" />
      </td>
```

{{currentView["avatarUrl"]}} is an object and this index contains the avatar images. Using the img tag this way is showing syntax error. By other means, how can I access v-for, for an object inside img source tag.

Comment: `:src="currentView.avatarUrl"`

Comment: or :src=" {{currentView['avatarUrl']}}"

Comment: It's not working. Nothing is being rendered. I read I have to added require through a function, but it's also not working.

Comment: Sorry. It worked now. Didn't really know why, but accessing it as "currentView.avatarUrl"  seems to be working fine now. Thanks alot!

Comment: `:src="currentView['avatarUrl']"`

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion. Using the v-bind for the src. I am assuming the avatar image is stored in the img folder. I removed the width because it seems that it will not display if the width setting is there.

```
<tr
      class="bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200"
      v-for="currentView in getDashboard()"
      :key="currentView.id"
    >
      <td class="px-4 py-3">
        <img 
          :src="require(`../img/${currentView.avatarUrl}`)"/>
      </td>
```